# Finding local maximum of a function containing absolute value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, absolute-value

I found an online answer to this question, but I think there is something wrong with it

**Question:** $f(x) = |x|^m |x - 1|^n, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

(m) and (n) are natural numbers (positive integers). The local maximum value for the function is:

a. $(1)$
b. $(m^n n^m)$
c. $(\frac{m^m n^n}{(m + n)^{m+n}})$
d. $(-\frac{(mn)^{mn}}{(m + n)^{m+n}})$

**Answer and Explanation:**

We have $f(X)= \begin{cases}(-1)^{m+n} x^m(x-1)^n & \text { if } x<0, \\ \\ \\ \\ (-1)^n x^m(x-1)^n & \text { if } 0 \leq x<1, \\ \\ \\ \\ x^m(x-1)^n & \text { if } x \geq 1\end{cases}$
Let $g(X)=x^m(x-1)^n$ Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& g'(x)=m x^{m-1}(x-1)^n+n x^m(x-1)^{n-1} \\
& =x^{m-1}(x-1)^{n-1}\{(m x-m+n x)\}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\text { Now } f(X)=0 \text { or } g(x)=0 \text { i.e } \\  x=0,1 \text { or } \frac{m}{m+n}
$$
$$
\mathrm{F}(\mathrm{0})=0, \\ \mathrm{f}(1)=0 \text { and }
$$
$$
f\left(\frac{m}{m+n}\right)=(-1)^n \frac{m^{m n^n(-1)^n}}{(m+n)^{m+n}}=\frac{m^m n^n}{(m+n)^{m+n}}>0
$$

thus the answer is **C**

I wonder from the beginning how $\frac{m}{m+n}$ is the x value at which the function is maximum because $\frac{m}{m+n}$ is smaller than 1
and $f(x) = x^m(x-1)^n  \text { only if } x \geq 1$

Comment: Note that the three branches of $f$ only differ for, at most, a factor $-1$, then the study of the critical points is the same for all three. And, indeed, $f(m/(m+n))$ is computed using the second branch.

Comment: An $x$ that satisfies $f'(x)=0$ is **not necessarily** a maxima, it is a stationary point. In this particular example, it happens to be a maxima of the function

Comment: I understood your point. But I want to know why when I get the derivative of the second branch and set it equal to zero, I don't get m / (m+n) as a critical point?